# Side to see all given "Express interest"

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

There is already the functionality to undo the click on the "Express interest" button.

At the moment there is an popup which is 30 seconds shown.

**Request**:

An area or an side where it is possible to see a list of given "Express interests" and the function that you can undo them.

**Why should it be needed:**

This function may be needed eg. If you already had contact with the company but this did not go well you can show it by withdrawing the interest.

In some other cases, it may also be that you only come after a few minutes that you may not be interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reasonable feature request and it’s closely related to another commonly requested feature: better tools to manage previously submitted applications.

We’ve had internal discussions about this, but unfortunately I don’t have a timeline I can share yet. It’s not on our roadmap for Q1 (Jan-Mar), however, it’s in line with the areas we’re looking to improve later this year.